# How to redirect a user with javascript while using ratchet?

Tags: ratchet-2

Normally to redirect a user in a website using javascript I'd use `window.location.replace("newpage.html");` however I've found that when using [Ratchet](http://goratchet.com/) this doesn't work. Does anyone know of a good way to make a ratchet application change pages using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [push.js](https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/blob/master/js/push.js) to see how the navigation mechanism is triggered. Ratchet auto-wires navigation to elements triggered on the touchend event. You can call PUSH with those properties directly.

```
PUSH({
  url        : "target.html",
  hash       : "#",
  timeout    : null,
  transition : "slide-in"
});
```